# no me retorna el str corrrectamente en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo 2 clases una hereda de ella para calcular el perimetro y superficie de una figura, el problema esta que la funcion del metodo especial **str** no me retorna todos los metodos correctamente

```
class Figura(object):
 def __init__(self,nombre):  
    self.nombre = nombre


class Cuadrado(Figura):
 def __init__(self,nombre,lado):
    if (nombre == 'Cuadrado'):
        if isinstance(lado, int):
            Figura.__init__(self, lado)
            self.lado=lado
            self.perimetro=0
            self.superficie=0

        else:
            raise TypeError("El valor del atributo lado debe ser numerico") 

    else:

        raise TypeError("El valor del atributo nombre debe ser cuadrado")  


def calcularPerimetro(self,lado):
    perimetro = 4 * lado
    if perimetro > 15:
        print("El valor del perimetro es mayor a 15")

    elif perimetro < 15:
        print("El valor del perimetro es menor que 15")

    return perimetro

def calcularSuperficie(self,lado):
    superficie = lado * lado
    if superficie % 2==0:
        print("El valor de la superficie es par")
    else:
        print("El valor de la superficie es impar")
    return superficie
#Aqui es el fallo que me surge
def __str__(self):
    cadena = "Un cuadrado de lado " + str(self.lado) + " tiene un perimetro " + str(self.perimetro) + " y una superficie de " + str(self.perimetro)
    return cadena
```

Este es el main

```
from EjercicioExamenFigura import *


nombre=input("Que nombre tiene tu figura")
lado=int(input("Cuanto mide el lado  de tu figura"))

cuadrado1=Cuadrado(nombre,lado)
print(cuadrado1.calcularPerimetro(lado))
print(cuadrado1.calcularSuperficie(lado))
print(cuadrado1)
```

Me imprime esto

```
Que nombre tiene tu figura Cuadrado
Cuanto mide el lado  de tu figura 4
El valor del perimetro es mayor a 15
16
El valor de la superficie es par
16
Un cuadrado de lado 4 tiene un perimetro 0 y una superficie de 0
```

> Un cuadrado de lado 4 tiene un perimetro 0 y una superficie de 0

Comment: Las funciones que calculan el perímetro y el área, además de retornar ese resultado, deben guardarlo en `self.area` y `self.perimetro`. Por cierto que la función `__str__()` está imprimiendo el perímetro donde debería imprimir el área. Ten en cuenta además que la representación str del cuadrado no será correcta hasta que no hayas llamado antes a `cuadrado.calcularSuperficie()` y `cuadrado.calcularArea()`, lo que no me parece muy correcto

Comment: claro tenia que llamar al atributo self.perimetro y self.superficie!

Answer (score 0):

El método **str** debe estar dentro de la clase Cuadrado. Aquí te adjunto la solución en Python 3:

```
class Figura(object):
    def __init__(self,nombre):  
        self.nombre = nombre

class Cuadrado(Figura):
    def __init__(self,nombre,lado):
        if (nombre == 'Cuadrado'):
            if isinstance(lado, int):
                Figura.__init__(self, lado)
                self.lado=lado
                self.perimetro=0
                self.superficie=0
            else:
                raise TypeError("El valor del atributo lado debe ser numerico") 
        else:
            raise TypeError("El valor del atributo nombre debe ser 'Cuadrado' con C mayúscula") 

    def __str__(self):
        cadena = "Un cuadrado de lado {} tiene un perimetro {} y una superficie de {}".format(self.lado, self.perimetro, self.lado*self.lado)
        return cadena  

def calcularPerimetro(self,lado):
    self.perimetro = 4 * lado
    if self.perimetro > 15:
        print("El valor del perimetro es mayor a 15")
    elif self.perimetro < 15:
        print("El valor del perimetro es menor que 15")
    return self.perimetro

def calcularSuperficie(self,lado):
    superficie = lado * lado
    if superficie % 2==0:
        print("El valor de la superficie es par")
    else:
        print("El valor de la superficie es impar")
    return superficie

nombre=input("¿Qué nombre tiene tu figura?\n")
lado=int(input("¿Cuánto mide el lado  de tu figura?\n"))

cuadrado1=Cuadrado(nombre,lado)
print(calcularPerimetro(cuadrado1,lado))
print(calcularSuperficie(cuadrado1, lado))
print(cuadrado1)
```

**Nota:** Trabajé todo en un solo archivo, así que queda de tu parte trabajarlo por módulos como lo hiciste antes. Te recomiendo que trabajes con .format() para la salida de datos, es mucho más cómodo. Y realmente no entiendo la restricción del nombre de la figura.

Answer (score -1):

Fijate que me parece que no estas asignado valor a las variables que queres mostras, mostras self.perimetro y en procesos haces referencia solamente a la variable perimetro, por ejemplo.
Un saludo y espero se de con la respuesta.

Comment: El valor es introducido por teclado amigo